# "The user is blocked from live streaming." (Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403)

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

When I'm trying to perform request for inserting of a broadcast I receive error:

> *Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "The user is blocked from live streaming."
> UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x28027ad30: {code:403
> errors:[1] message:"The user is blocked from live streaming."},
> NSLocalizedDescription=The user is blocked from live streaming.}*

I have started receiving this error today. Before, everything has been working fine. I have tested on several accounts and had not any luck.

#### Code:

```
GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet *broadcastSnippet= [[GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet alloc] init];
    [broadcastSnippet setTitle:title];
    [broadcastSnippet setScheduledStartTime:[GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:self.beginOfStream]]; // current date + 1 minute.
    [broadcastSnippet setScheduledEndTime:[GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:80000]]];
    
    GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus *status = [[GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus alloc] init];
    [status setPrivacyStatus:[StreamSettings youtubeStringForPrivacyStatus:[privacyStatus intValue]]];
    
    GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcastContentDetails *details = [self streamDetailsWith:latency];
    
    GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcast *broadcast = [[GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcast alloc] init];
    [broadcast setKind:@"youtube#liveBroadcast"];
    [broadcast setSnippet:broadcastSnippet];
    [broadcast setStatus:status];
    
    GTLRYouTubeQuery_LiveBroadcastsInsert *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_LiveBroadcastsInsert queryWithObject:broadcast
                                                                                part:@"id, snippet, contentDetails,status"];
    GTLRYouTubeService *service = self.youTubeService;
    __strong id <YouTubeHelperDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                    GTLRYouTube_LiveBroadcast *returnedBrocast,
                                                    NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error); //Here is place I got an error 
        }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the logged in user does not have more than 1000 subscribers he can't go live using a mobile app, as mentioned in link:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834?hl=en